# knockoutjs - how do I reuse my view model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Devs,

let's say I have the knockout js view model example below and I wanted to manage 100 'Person objects'. I wouldn't want to recreate the code below 100 times, so is there another way to use binding with knockoutjs and manage a large number of items?

```
function PersonAppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = "Bert";
  this.lastName = "Bertington";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use collections. For example, viewmodel has collection Persons. View binds to viewmodels Persons property. You can see example [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html).

Comment: Awesome! Hey, the example even has People. Perfect. Thanks!